# Sed -e and awk for processing a text file

Tags: bash, shell, kaldi

This code is taking all the .stm file from a directory and after executing this code saving in a file.

```
cat db/some_path/stm/*.stm | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k4,4n | \
      sed -e 's:<F0_M>:<o,f0,male>:' \
          -e 's:<F0_F>:<o,f0,female>:' \
          -e 's:([0-9])::g' \
          -e 's:<sil>::g' \
          -e 's:([^ ]*)$::' | \
      awk '{ $2 = "A"; print $0; }'
  } | local/join_suffix.py > data/dev.orig/stm
```

Sample output

```
AimeeMullins_2009P A inter_segment_gap 0 17.82 <o,,unknown> ignore_time_segment_in_scoring
AimeeMullins_2009P A AimeeMullins 17.82 28.81 <o,f0,female> i'd like to share with you a discovery that i made a few months ago while writing an article for italian wired i always keep my thesaurus handy whenever i'm writing anything but
AimeeMullins_2009P A AimeeMullins 28.81 40.266 <o,f0,female> i'd already finished editing the piece and i realized that i had never once in my life looked up the word disabled to see what i'd find let me read you the entry
AimeeMullins_2009P A inter_segment_gap 40.266 41.418 <o,,unknown> ignore_time_segment_in_scoring
```

I don't understand using sed -e how to format it.

what I understand
`awk '{ $2 = "A"; print $0; }'` this line meaning for each row take the 2nd word and check if it's equal to A then print 1st word, but what are those `-e 's:<sil>::g'` meaning?

Comment: You don't understand the `awk` bit either if that's what you think it does... it sets the second column to A and then prints the entire modified line.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the later one please ?